# Custom sbt task that compiles JavaScript and is activated only in production mode

Tags: scala, playframework, webpack, sbt

I know that I can write my own `sbt` tasks and that I can create dependencies between them. The task hierarchy seems a bit complicated to me and that's what I'm struggling with: **I don't know on which tasks my task should depend**. Here is the situation.

My Scala/Play web application has a quite complicated front-end written in JavaScript/React which is compiled with `webpack`. During development I'm using `webpack-dev-server`. It's faster and supports features like hot reloading. Nevertheless, when deploying in production mode, I would like to build my frontend using `sbt`. That means that for `sbt start` or `sbt dist`, I want to get my frontend compiled together with the Scala sources, but for `sbt run` this phase should be completely omitted (as it takes quite a lot of time and `webpack-dev-server` takes care of that).

**I created my own sbt task that pretty much just runs `npm install && npm run build` but I don't know where to hook it.**

I think the situation is even more complicated because of the way "assets" are treated by `sbt`. There is a `public` folder in my project that contains assets like styles, scripts or images. This stuff is copied to the `target` folder by the build process and is then available in the final app. In my current solution, the original React/JavaScript files are kept separated and the custom sbt task compiles it into the `public` folder from where the compiled bundle is copied to the `target` folder. That's the intended workflow but at this point the custom sbt task has to be invoked manually. I want to automate the whole process but I don't know where to hook my task to compile the JavaScript before it's copied to the `target` folder. I tried to go with the `copyResource` task, something like this:

```
(copyResources in Compile) <<= (copyResources in Compile) dependsOn buildJs
```

That seems to be working but the problem is that the custom task (`buildJs`) is triggered also when running in development mode (i. e. `sbt run`). Which is something that I want to avoid.

Another approach I tried was to compile the JavaScript directly to the `target` folder. The files appeared in the correct location but the application wasn't aware of them. They weren't available. HTTP requests to get any of those files were returning empty responses.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

So, the tasks that should depend on my custom task (that builds the JavaScript) are `stage` and `dist`. This is my `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val buildJs = taskKey[Unit]("Build JavaScript frontend")
buildJs := {
  println("Building JavaScript frontend...")
  "npm install" #&& "npm run build" !
}

stage <<= stage dependsOn buildJs
dist <<= dist dependsOn buildJs
```

This task is activated only for `sbt start` and `sbt dist` but not for `sbt run` (= development mode). For that I use a separated instance of `webpack-dev-server` which handles the JavaScript compilation.

It's possible that there is a simpler way but this is what worked for me.

If you decide to use this way to integrate `webpack` into `sbt`, the last missing piece of puzzle is loading the proper JavaScript file depending on the current mode (in production mode, you need the compiled bundle, in development mode, you need to point the page to the `webpack` server). The point is that in order to take the advantage of all `webpack` features (like hot reloading and hot React components replacement), you can't serve the JavaScripts through the Scala Play server from a static file, it has to be the `webpack` server. Theoretically, it could be possible to turn the Scala server into some kind of proxy, nevertheless, the following solution worked for me and is really simple (part of `index.scala.html`):

```
@if(play.Play.isDev()) {
    <script src="http://localhost:9090/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:9090/build/@{bundleName}.bundle.js"></script>
} else {
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/" + bundleName + ".bundle.js")"></script>
}
```